# twitter date time parsing

Tags: pandas, datetime, twitter

I have a column from twitter dataframe which has date format as `Sat Apr 07 16:49:49 +0000 2018`. based on this date I want a new column for extracting the timestamp, and AM/PM in new columns. For first query I tried this but it did not work. `from dateutil import parser
spear['ModDate']  = parser.parse(separ['created_at'])`. Please how this code can work in python notebook.

Comment: How working my solution?

Comment: thanks it works but I don't need hour, minutes and seconds, how to remove it. I think I have to use some format.

Comment: Do you need `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date` ?

Comment: I have developed like this `separ['date2'] = separ.date.dt.strftime('%d%m%y')`, it allows me to create a kind of frequency index which I shall be using in later analysis.

Comment: yes, it is good solution if need custom strings from dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'date':['Sat Apr 07 16:49:49 +0000 2018','Sat Apr 07 16:49:49 +0000 2018']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print (df)
                 date
0 2018-04-07 16:49:49
1 2018-04-07 16:49:49
```

Comment: Sure, I had little idea about it.

Comment: @ambrishdhaka - Thank you.